# Can't mount "Windows Disk" after installing ubuntu

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I can't mount or even boot my windows disk after I installed ubuntu. Can anyone help me, how can I solve this, please?

Error message:

```
Couldn't analyze partition: Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/mapos/7670A71A70A6DFDB: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/mapos/7670A71A70A6DFDB"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0). Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount. Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Operation not permitted The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume read-only with the'ro'mount option.
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj, not really, I can't boot my Windows.

Comment: are you using windows 8 alongside ? or is it win7

Comment: @akki, Windows 8 is on 500GB drive and ubuntu on another 320GB drive

Comment: checkout if your windows disk's space is allocated or unallocated.

Comment: see @Mitch's answer it would help you http://askubuntu.com/questions/384429/cannot-remove-hiberfile-on-ntfs-partition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually mount the filesystem in read only mode.

Check to see if you have a mount point (folder for mounting your partition in) for your Windows partition in the folder /media using this command:

```
 ls /media
```

If you don't see a folder for your Windows partition, you should create one with the following command:

```
 sudo mkdir /media/windows
```

Next, mount the partition in read-only mode onto this folder with this command:

```
 mount -t ntfs -o ro /dev/sdb1 /media/windows
```

Note that you should change /media/windows if your mountpoint is called something else.Also, here I am assuming your windows drive is sdb1.

Now you will be able to view/open files on your Windows partition using any program in Ubuntu. However you will not be able to write to the partition or modify any files as it is in read only mode.

For more : [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation/145904#145904)

Check if you still have your windows system data in it.If yes then maybe restarting your  PC should do the work.

Comment: I have done this and can't see this volume anymore. //Edit: Ok, I can see it.

Comment: I can see my files but there are certain files that I am denied read permission despite using sudo!
Could this be because of the windows user permissions on that file?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The only way I could fix it was through my windows CD. Only that my windows was xp not 8.

You should boot your computer form your windows CD and access the recovery console then use the command "chkdsk".

this link might help

http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-8-recovery-environment-command-prompt/#commands

Answer (score 0):

> Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume read-only with the'ro'mount option

The message is pretty clear. Boot Windows and **shut it down** (no hibernation or fast restarting). Or mount the filesystem as read only.

You may want to run `chkdsk /f` in Windows too just in case.

Comment: he says that he can't able to boot into windows os.