# Automatically running ntfsfix on boot?

Tags: partitioning, mount, ntfs

Recently, I set up a nice symlink system so my documents and various things are synced between my Ubuntu and Windows installs. However, this depends (obviously) on my Windows partition being mounted and being healthy.

The problem is that Windows and NTFS like being annoying -- marking the filesystem as "dirty" and requiring `ntfsfix` to repair it to allow a drive mount.

Is there a way to run `ntfsfix` if the partition fails? If so, how? Is this even a safe thing to do?

Comment: The "fix" really is to disable suspend/fastboot on Windows instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to run ntfsfix if the partition fails

Yes, a method would be to create a UDEV rule ([example with an external USB](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=142475)) and add a "ACTION" to run a script that. In that script you can check the health of the disk and, when needed,  run `ntsfix`.

> Is this even a safe thing to do?

I have my doubts. It will delete data from your Windows if that data is only stored in the Windows hiberfile. The correct way to fix this is by turning off hibernation/suspend/fast boot from Windows.

Command line `powercfg -h off` to turn it off.

Comment: Apparently `remove_hiberfile` [no longer works](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384429/cannot-remove-hiberfile-on-ntfs-partition). I will never understand why NTFS needs to be so annoying.

Comment: Naa it is not NTFS. Microsoft. They will always try to annoy users of other systems.