# Unable to mount a hard drive due to windows 8 hibernation

Tags: mount, hibernate

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop, and I had a problem when I want to mount a hard drive due to windows 8 hibernation.

The problem is that when I was partitioning my hard drive I formated the drive which contained Windows 8 without shutting down Windows, I only did a hibernation, so now I can't resume and shutdown Windows fully.

Now I can only mount my hard drive as read-only.

How can I solve this problem ??

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Boot with windows and in cmd type `powercfg -h off` to disable hibernation and then try boot with Ubuntu this will fix.

Also you can fix that from Ubuntu:

Use `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdXY` where `XY` is the partition name. ex:sda4. use gparted to find partition name.

Comment: I can't boot with windows I've deleted it from my computer isn't there any other way to do it from Ubuntu  ?

Comment: Nope still getting: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount. By using ntfsfix.

Comment: @MelroyvandenBerg surprising i'm still facing this in 2022 and no better answers have come, ntfs-3g and ntfsfix can't help

Comment: I just not using Windows anymore, "solved my problem"