# Blkid does not return uuid of windows, windows is not in fstab, and windows is hibernated so it cannot be mounted

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, mount, fstab

So the windows partition for windows 7 while running dual boot 14.10 does appear when fdisk is run. However, it does not appear when blkid runs and there is no way for me to check the uuid because the drive has disappeared from fstab. The windows boot is also gone from grub. Any help from anybody would be appreciated?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I mount a hibernated NTFS partition?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/204166/how-do-i-mount-a-hibernated-ntfs-partition)

Comment: see here http://askubuntu.com/a/204173/167115 and here http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation and run `sudo update-grub` after you are done. If it still doesn't recognize windows, you may need to run `bootrec` from a windows repair or installation disk . . .  just don't run `bootrec /fixmbr`

Comment: also, to view the UUID, run the following command: `blkid | grep ntfs`

Comment: The only problem is that windows is unmountable because it is not present in fstab and to place it in fstab I need the uuid. blkid only returns what is present in fstab. Basically, I am stuck in a circle where I need to boot into windows to be able to add the information to GRUB to boot into windows.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's in fstab; that just means it won't automatically mount when you boot. Either try running 'blkid' with 'sudo' or run 'lsblk' instead to find out the device name like /dev/sda1 for example. You don't actually need the uuid to run those fixes. Also, it should show up when you run gparted, have you tried that?

Comment: it does show up in gparted; however, when I try to mount from terminal I get the error that /dev/sda1 (the Windows partition) cannot be found in /etc/fstab.

Comment: lsblk does show the partition, but blkid does not.

Comment: That's because you need to create a mount point to mount the partition at. I believe this is discussed in one of the links I have provided. `sudo mkdir /media/windows` then run the mount command as mentioned in the other post followed by `/media/windows/` in the same command at the end after the device (/dev/sda1 for example)

Comment: Is it /dev/sda1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Warning, this will delete any unsaved data in from your hibernated windows session!

Assuming the device is /dev/sda1:

```
sudo mkdir /media/windows


sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sda1 /media/windows
```

Now, you should be able to run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

and windows should be recognized.