# Windows not booting correctly -- Need help!

Tags: windows

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad T430s with Ubuntu 15.04 and Windows 8.1 installed. For a long time, everything worked fine. However, the last time I tried to boot into Windows from GRUB, it showed the Windows boot screen, and everything was fine. After the boot screen, the screen goes black.

I believe I disabled fast-boot in Windows. However, when I attempt to access the Windows files, a window comes up saying:

Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sda2: Command-line `mount "/media/sda2"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.

What do I do? Has anyone had this problem?
Edit: I forgot to mention that I have to boot into Ubuntu using upstart mode. If I try normally booting into Ubuntu, it puts the computer in "emergency mode".

Comment: This error is from grub, possibly resulting from you hibernating windows *or ubuntu* whilst the windows partition is mounted.

Comment: The error message tells you how to fix the problem - "Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting)" If you do not use windows , do not use ntfs

Comment: I would do that bodhi, but I cannot boot into windows.

Comment: Probably need to restore windows from a recovery disk. Ask on a windows forum and check any error messages. For now, mount the partition ro `mount /dev/sdxy /mount/point -o ro` and recover your data.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll try a recovery disk when I get home.

Comment: No, just delete the windows hiber file, this is a duplicate of how to delete windows hibernation file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I mount a hibernated NTFS partition?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/204166/how-do-i-mount-a-hibernated-ntfs-partition)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/204173/167115