# Why do we have to lose hibernation data when we mount NTFS read-write?

Tags: windows, hibernate

I understand that hibernation prevents (by default) the user from mounting their disk in read-write mode on Ubuntu. Attempting to use read-write forces erasure of `hiberfil.sys`.

How do I keep `hiberfil.sys` (and still mount read-write)?

**Note: I am aware of the data risks, but there must be a way to do this! It seems that the driver must mount and then erase hiberfil.sys.**

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation for the "why". There seems to be no possible "how" though.

Comment: Otherwise read http://askubuntu.com/questions/204166/how-do-i-mount-a-hibernated-ntfs-partition Basically: not possible due to restraint on the driver. and it would lead to data loss if you could (and possibly an unbootable/unusable windows machine). We do not need that kind of problems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I mount a hibernated NTFS partition?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/204166/how-do-i-mount-a-hibernated-ntfs-partition)

Comment: @Pilot6 not a dupe