# SSD, HDD, legacy and a really messed up situation with GRUB - how to revive lost windows and have dual boot with ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

So I messed up. Like really.

But let's start from the start.

A few hours ago I decided I need Ubuntu in my life, as my work laptop was being purged for the new owner. 
As I am a man of my words I installed the latest version of Ubuntu.

My thought process was as follow:

1. I have my SSD for Windows 10 and games
2. I will use HDD for Ubuntu and work

Sounds simple, right? 
As I thought I did. I have formatted the HDD, created a 100GB partition and was happy to configure Ubuntu. But wait.

Why I see no GRUB!? So here goes moment 1.

Fast googling, ha! there is a solution: 
https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

I did it, once, twice, three times... No results. I tried - I hope every configuration. below one of many versions of outputs:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wmHwNH8YF3/

OK - I did more research on the booting options. This is a Windows issue - no problem. I have created the win 10 booting USB and begun the fun time of fixing it - nothing worked. 
UNTIL. 
Until I figured out I will purge all of the partition except the one that is with windows and games - because... I have no clue why. Honestly, I just don't.

As I said - I am a man of my words - so I removed it all.

And now I am in a puzzle as I do not have a clue what to do next.

And I will not reinstall windows. I have there too many GB to download I just started Divinity Original Sin 2 and I loved it!

Help me out guys - as I am empty and I have no clue what to do next.

Comment: A common problem with people who install Linux on systems that already have Windows is that they don't actually shut windows down since Windows 10 goes into a "soft power off' state. This causes problems because when they turn Windows back on it starts writing information over the hard drive that was kept in memory before Windows essentially hibernated.

Comment: Your paste shows that you still have NTFS partitions, so those files aren't lost most likely. However, I'm unable to understand what your actual question is or how to help you because the post contains too much information that may or may not be relevant.

Comment: I believe I turned windows down. That or another the problem is I can not access windows - I can start only Ubuntu.

Comment: @KristopherIves what information should I provide now?

Comment: Trust me - I am as puzzled as you are. I do not have a clue what to do/check/adjust now. I was always believing I am a person that can handle a grub configuration.

Comment: It's possible Windows was installed as UEFI and Linux was not, or some other combination that doesn't match.

Comment: @KristopherIves It is that is true. On the other hand, I was not changing anything in my BIOS and by default it was in legacy mode.

Comment: here is the LATEST pastebin from boot-repair tool run on default: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/WvtcWZvPpd/

Comment: the problem I see there is this: Windows not detected by os-prober on sda1.

Comment: In your log it says "Windows is hibernated, refused to mount."

Comment: Like I mentioned originally Microsoft has made it very obscure of a process to actually shut Windows down completely. Almost all "regular" methods will hibernate it.

Comment: Kind sir! Thank you! You are a lifesaver! 
Now to unfu... unhibernate it - I am starting my google!

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/204166/how-do-i-mount-a-hibernated-ntfs-partition

Comment: One step closer - two steps back: 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/VXY5mNTzMB/ 

Windows not detected on sda1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find a solution that would allow me to have Windows working. 
I was able to have the Ubuntu working fine.

In a long run, I did a format and ran a clean installation of Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Because your Windows drive is MBR, your Windows install is in BIOS boot mode.
And since you have two drives, you should always use Something Else install option and install grub2's boot loader to Ubuntu drive. Default is normally first drive and most often sda/Window drive. 
But you want to keep Windows boot loader in MBR of Windows drive.

When you installed Windows was BIOS set to default boot from HDD? Windows 7 or later normally uses a separate Boot partition with two boot files, bootmgr & /boot/BCD. But you are totally missing those files. They can be in same partition as main install or c:, but normally are not.
You must use Windows repair/recovery disk to fully repair Windows.
Make sure BIOS is set to boot Windows drive. Only after Windows boots, then set BIOS to boot HDD and use grub to dual boot.

Also with multiple drives do not run Boot-Repair's auto-fix. That installs grub to every drive's MBR, so no matter what settings you have in BIOS, it will boot grub. You actually want BIOS set to boot Ubuntu drive, but have Windows boot loader in Windows drive. Grub only boots working Windows or Windows that is not hibernated/fast boot on. And Windows with updates will turn fast start up back on.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: When you installed Windows was BIOS set to default boot from HDD - no I was booting from SSD. I believe at least. 

You are correct - as for the partition - I purged it.

Comment: OK - so if I understood you correctly: a) I am changing in BIOS the order of booting disks (now it is hdd > sdd). b) I am starting a recovery disck and going with the repair windows mode (this did not work before)

Comment: Windows Repair may not have worked if BIOS set to boot Ubuntu drive as Windows could not see NTFS partition with boot flag. That is where it will install/repair boot files.

Comment: Tried. Repair found nothing, fixed nothing.

Comment: Run new copy of Boot-Repair's summary report. Need to see if you now have Windows boot files. If you have copy of bootmgr you can copy that into your Windows c: drive. And possible use third party tools to create the /boot/BCD file. Otherwise best to try a Windows forum for Windows issues.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/8pT4m3fFJm/ - latest update. os-prober still don't see Windows installation.

Comment: You are now showing the BCD, but not bootmgr for Windows to boot. There may be a copy somewhere else in Windows, but do not remember. Try repairs again or ask at Windows forum.

Comment: Question asked here: https://forum.thewindowsclub.com/windows-10-management-support/50836-windows-10-broken-mbr-bootmanager-after-dual-boot-ubuntu.html#post190531 

I am really lost, I did all I found on google. I think I will have to reinstall this whole setup.

Comment: If you have a Windows repair disk, does it not have a copy of bootmgr? If so copy that into your C: drive One level up from /boot/BCD or top level.

Comment: Interesting fact - you can't. 
To all who are interested - I gave up, reinstalled windows again and then reinstalled Ubuntu. All works.

Comment: Make full backup and recovery/repair flash drive for Windows. And develop a good backup procedure for Ubuntu. For Ubuntu I assume I will just reinstall & restore data & settings, so I do not backup system.

Comment: I have a similar but not identical situation, for which I'm creating the question "How can I revive a lost Window installation?"

Comment: @Paul A. If answers here do not help, better to start your own question. But this site is for offical flavors of Ubuntu. You may want to try a Windows forum or https://superuser.com/